# Links to Excel files in doc libraries are opening differently for different users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, excel-services

I have a link to an Excel file in a doc library that opens in Excel Online. When opening it, some users are getting prompted to open the file in Excel 2016 and some users are getting prompted to open with 'Url:Excel Protocol. Due to network restrictions, all users who are prompted to open with 'Url:Excel Protocol' are not able to open the document. I need everyone to be prompted to open in Excel 2016. Any way to make this consistent for all users? I appreciate any ideas! Thanks!

Here is how my link is formatted: /sites/TEAMSite/TEST%20Documents/TEST_742/FY18%20TEST%20Doc%20TEST%20Rev2.xlsm?Web=1

[image: some are seeing this]

[image: and others are seeing this]

Comment: Please provide some details: browsers are IE (or smth else) in both cases, security settings are the same?

Comment: @AlexZh Browser is Chrome and security settings are the same in both cases. Thanks for you help!